# How to show code in Mobile device in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I need add a custom code in Prestashop 1.7 only for Mobile visits. Css display none is not the solution I am looking for. In previous PS 1.6 the code what works was {if $isMobile} and checking PS 1.7 file classes/Context.php yet is included the variable "isMobile".

I tried add a {if $isMobile} or {if $mobile_device} in .tpl files but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into the `getWidgetVariables()` function of your controller module, you can add the following line into array returned:

`'mobile_device' => Context::getContext()->isMobile(),`

And check into your .tpl:

```
{if isset($mobile_device) && $mobile_device}
 <p>Displayed only on mobile</p> 
{/if}
```